# How to read the strength of AMD CPUs from their models?

Tags: cpu

When buying a laptop, anyone can understand the strength of an Intel CPU, as they are mainly classified with the classes of i3, i5 and i7 plus straightforward generations. But it is difficult to guess the strength and advancement of an AMD CPU from its model.

Is there a way or chart to simply check an AMD CPU and its equivalency with rival Intel CPU?

Comment: AMD is so far behind Intel in processor technology, there is no comparison in my opinion, stick with Intel.

Comment: @Moab Although there is some truth to your statement, particularly in the server CPU market, and it really doesn't do anything to get to an answer for the OP's question. AMD clearly makes quality CPUs, which cost wise can be an exceptional value compared to roughly equivalent Intel models especially in the desktop market.  The OPs question had nothing to do with which one was "better".

Comment: And that's probably why it was a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I did answer it, there is no comparison.........

Comment: Best page to use to compare AMD cpu's is this one...https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php

Comment: also, don't be fooled into thinking i3 i5 & i7 are in increasing order of 'power'. Intel have made consumer choice between those three 'families' an order of difficulty greater than the poor consumer really deserves.

Comment: It's not easy to compare i3,5,7. There may be some overlaps performance wise. i.e. Some i5 may perform better than some i7.

Answer (score 2):

Although it isn't necessarily a "real world" scenario, the best way to determine this is by using benchmarks. There are several sites that allow you review and compare CPU benchmarks, such as [PassMark Software's site](http://www.cpubenchmark.net/index.php) or [AnandTech's CPU Benchmarks](http://www.anandtech.com/bench/CPU/39).

BTW, as you look at the benchmarks on these sites, you might find that Intel is not quite as "straightforward" as you thought.